# Windows media foundation enumerating Camera devices

Tags: c++, windows, ms-media-foundation

[image]I would like to enumerate the camera devices on my computer using Windows Media Foundation, I used the code on Microsoft : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940326(v=vs.85).aspx
I reproduced the same code they use here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663604(v=vs.85).aspx

When I used their code I get my webcam device name, however my code doesn't find any camera capture device. I'm enable to find why.

Here is the code :

```
    #pragma once
#include <new>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mfapi.h>
#include <mfidl.h>
#include <mfreadwrite.h>
#include <Wmcodecdsp.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <Dbt.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <mfplay.h>

#include <iostream>


const UINT WM_APP_PREVIEW_ERROR = WM_APP + 1;    // wparam = HRESULT

class DeviceList
{
    UINT32      m_cDevices; // contains the number of devices
    IMFActivate **m_ppDevices; // contains properties about each device

public:
    DeviceList() : m_ppDevices(NULL), m_cDevices(0)
    {

    }
    ~DeviceList()
    {
        Clear();
    }

    UINT32  Count() const { return m_cDevices; }

    void    Clear();
    HRESULT EnumerateDevices();
    HRESULT GetDevice(UINT32 index, IMFActivate **ppActivate);
    HRESULT GetDeviceName(UINT32 index, WCHAR **ppszName);
};




#include "DeviceList.h"

/*
* A templated Function SafeRelease releasing pointers memories
* @param ppT the pointer to release
*/

template <class T> void SafeRelease(T **ppT)
{
    if (*ppT)
    {
        (*ppT)->Release();
        *ppT = NULL;
    }
}



/*
* A function which copy attribute form source to a destination
* @ param pSrc is an Interface to store key/value pairs of an Object
* @ param pDest is an Interface to store key/value pairs of an Object
* @ param GUID is an unique identifier
* @ return HRESULT return errors warning condition on windows
*/

HRESULT CopyAttribute(IMFAttributes *pSrc, IMFAttributes *pDest, const GUID& key);




/*
* A Method form DeviceList which clear the list of Devices
*/

void DeviceList::Clear()
{
    for (UINT32 i = 0; i < m_cDevices; i++)
    {
        SafeRelease(&m_ppDevices[i]);
    }
    CoTaskMemFree(m_ppDevices);
    m_ppDevices = NULL;

    m_cDevices = 0;
}


/*
* A function which enumerate the list of Devices.
* @ return HRESULT return errors warning condition on windows
*/
HRESULT DeviceList::EnumerateDevices()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IMFAttributes *pAttributes = NULL;

    this->Clear();

    // Initialize an attribute store. We will use this to
    // specify the enumeration parameters.
    std::cout << "Enumerate devices" << std::endl;
    hr = MFCreateAttributes(&pAttributes, 1);

    // Ask for source type = video capture devices
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Enumerate devices" << std::endl;
        hr = pAttributes->SetGUID(
            MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE,
            MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID
            );
    }
    // Enumerate devices.
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "Enumerate devices:" << m_cDevices << std::endl;
        hr = MFEnumDeviceSources(pAttributes, &m_ppDevices, &m_cDevices);
    }

    SafeRelease(&pAttributes);

    return hr;
}


/*
* A function which copy attribute form source to a destination
* @ param index the index in an array
* @ param ppActivate is an Interface to store key/value pairs of an Object
* @ return HRESULT return errors warning condition on windows
*/


HRESULT DeviceList::GetDevice(UINT32 index, IMFActivate **ppActivate)
{
    if (index >= Count())
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    *ppActivate = m_ppDevices[index];
    (*ppActivate)->AddRef();

    return S_OK;
}


/*
* A function which get the name of the devices
* @ param index the index in an array
* @ param ppszName Name of the device
*/


HRESULT DeviceList::GetDeviceName(UINT32 index, WCHAR **ppszName)
{
    std::cout << "Get Device name" << std::endl;
    if (index >= Count())
    {
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    hr = m_ppDevices[index]->GetAllocatedString(
        MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_FRIENDLY_NAME,
        ppszName,
        NULL
        );

    return hr;
}


#include <iostream>
#include "DeviceList.h"

HRESULT UpdateDeviceList()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    WCHAR *szFriendlyName = NULL;

    DeviceList g_devices;


    g_devices.Clear();

    hr = g_devices.EnumerateDevices();

    if (FAILED(hr)) { goto done; }
    std::cout << "Nb devices found:"<< g_devices.Count() << std::endl;

    for (UINT32 iDevice = 0; iDevice < g_devices.Count(); iDevice++)
    {
        //std::cout << "" << std::endl;
        hr = g_devices.GetDeviceName(iDevice, &szFriendlyName);
        if (FAILED(hr)) { goto done; }
        std::cout << szFriendlyName << std::endl;
        // The list might be sorted, so the list index is not always the same as the
        // array index. Therefore, set the array index as item data.
        CoTaskMemFree(szFriendlyName);
        szFriendlyName = NULL;
    }
    std::cout << "End of EnumDeviceList" << std::endl;
done:
    return hr;
}



int main()
{
    std::cout <<"Main" << std::endl;
    UpdateDeviceList();
while (1);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: I just tested your code, and your code works fine (finds all cameras).  What specifically the issue?

Comment: For me it's not working, my devices are not enumerated. I don't find why.
I export the executable file on an other computer no devices has been found. I've updated the topic to show you my results.
Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are expected to do `MFStartup(MF_VERSION);` before you start calling other Media Foundation API functions.

Then you print `m_cDevices` before it is getting initialized one line below by `MFEnumDeviceSources`.

```
    std::cout << "Enumerate devices:" << m_cDevices << std::endl;
    hr = MFEnumDeviceSources(pAttributes, &m_ppDevices, &m_cDevices);
```

Having this fixed, your code will start getting you the devices.